# Wildfly Maven deploy ClassNotFoundException but it's there

Tags: java, maven-3, war, classnotfoundexception, wildfly-9

I'm facing a very weird scenario where a particular java file within my project is somehow not being `seen` by wildfly when deploying.

This is the actual error

```
2017-02-21 15:30:25,069 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit.obby.POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.obby.POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "obby"
```

The following is the the causing problem

```
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bd.domain.repository.VehicleEAO from [Module \"deployment.obby:main\" from Service Module Loader]
```

That particular class `bd.domain.repository.VehicleEAO` is in a package within my web project. The deployment works fine in the local wildly on my machine but when i'm doing remote deployment to another machine within my office network i get this error. I have clean and rebuilt the project several times to no avail. What could possibly be the issue? both machines are running the same Java version `1.8.0_121`, same wildfly `9.0.2.Final` version using same wildfly-maven-plugin `1.0.2.Final`

Comment: What is the name of the deployment? It looks like it's `obby` and should likely be `obby.war`.

Comment: Let me check why it's getting that extension name

Comment: @Obby Were you able to resolve your issue? I'm having the same issue with Wildfly 11 now

Comment: @Jules I wish I can remember what i did to make it work. Let me check the project again and see what changed

Comment: @Obby I solved it a few minutes ago. In my case I had some annotations that are not correct

Comment: @Jules great. I left that project a long time ago, would take me time to check it out